# When is $f$ one-to-one when it is linear?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I know that the below statement is true

> Let $f$ be a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. $f$ is one-to-one if and only if the determinant of the matrix of $f$ is not zero.

If $f$ is linear, then $f=Ax$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose that $\det(A)\not=0$. Suppose also that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. I can write this as $Ax_1=Ax_2$ and by left-multiply each side by $A^{-1}$, I get $x_1=x_2$. This shows that $f$ is one-to-one.

Now suppose that $f$ is one-to-one; this means $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$. I can write $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ as $Ax_1=Ax_2$ or as $A(x_1-x_2)=0$ since $x_1=x_2$, that leads to $A\cdot0=0$.

I am not sure how to use $A\cdot0=0$ to show that $\det(A)\not=0$.

Comment: How are you calculating $\det A$ when $n \not= m$?

Comment: Your linear function is between vector spaces with seemingly different dimensions. The matrix of $f$ isn't square. You can't talk about its determinant in this case.

Comment: Oh, you are right so $f$ should be from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I will edit my question now.

Comment: @Scientifica: I have edited the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes it does now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the determinant of $A$ is the product of its eigenvalues, then you're done. Indeed, by injectivity of $f$, you can show that $Av=0\implies v=0$. Hence $0$ isn't an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore $\det{A}\neq 0$.

**Edit:** Another think you can use is the fact that the determinant of $A$ is $0$ if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. If $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is the basis on which you're working, then $\det{A}=0$ if and only if $(f(e_1),\dots,f(e_n))$ is linearly dependent. Since $f$ is injective, you can show that this not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think that $A(x_1-x_2)=0$ can be written as $Ax=0$ where $x=x_1-x_2$ so since $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$, we want $Ax=0$ to only have trivial solution (otherwise $x_1\not= x_2$ and so $f$ would not be one-to-one). $Ax=0$ has trivial solution when $A$ is invertible and $A$ is invertible when $\det(A)\not=0$.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @Scientifica: Thanks for confirming. I accepted your answer to thank for your time and effort to help me. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pleasure :)